# Random uniform selection of point on hypersurface

Tags: probability

How can I randomly select a point $\vec p=\langle p_1,p_2,p_3...p_n\rangle$ such that all coordinates $p_i$ are between $0$ and $1$, and  $$\sum_{i=1}^n\ p_i = 1$$
Notice that  $\vec p$ lies on a hyperplane. I want the distribution of points on this hyperplane to be uniform. Specifically, the distribution an individual value $p_i$ should follow the probability density function $P(x)=(n-1)(1-x)^{n-2}$ when $0\leq x\leq 1$

One way to generate a point that follows this distribution is to repeatedly generate $n-1$ coordinates $p_1,p_2, ... p_{n-1}$ independent of each other with a uniform distribution in the range $[0,1]$ until finding a set of $n-1$ values whose sum is less than 1. The final value is easy to calculate: $$p_n=1-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\ p_i$$
Although the issue with this approach is that the average the number of initial sets of $n-1$ coordinates that have to be generated before finding one that works grows exponentially, and so this method wouldn't work before the heat death of the universe for $n>100$

Comment: In other words, you want a uniformly random probability distribution on a finite set?

Comment: Wouldn't it be a uniformly random probability distribution on an infinite set?

Comment: Oh I thought $n$ was fixed.

Comment: Arg... $n$ is fixed, but you're selecting a point from an infinite set of possible points.

Comment: Okay, so a point satisfying your conditions is equivalent to a probability distribution on a finite set of $n$ points.

Comment: I think you can randomize numbers with any equidistributed non-negative uniform distribution and then just divide by the sum you end up getting. I don't have a proof though.

Comment: Anyway, one way (provided I'm understanding your set up)  to draw from your *standard* simplex is: 1) realize it as the graph of a linear function obtained as the inverse of the projection onto the first $n$ coordinates. 2) this doesn't preserve area, but it distorts regions by a constant factor, so drawing uniformly from the projection will draw uniformly from the simplex. To draw from the projection, observe that you can flip it across its face opposite to the origin to get a hypercube, which you can draw from uniformly and do rejection sampling.

Comment: I might be missing something, but is this not answered by [uniformly drawing from a probability simplex](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3227/uniform-sampling-from-a-simplex)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Random_number_generation